# How Can one transfer Hard Drive files from Virtual computer to the Host OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, transfer, vdi

I want to transfer some files from my Virtualbox MS-DOS 7.10 to my Windows 7 PC (Not virtualized). I have tried: 
Shared Folders: It need to install the vbox addition (can't on Maddox). 
 
Inserting a CD (Don't have a floppy, and USBS don't work): needs to be formatted. FAIL.
 So, can I extract the Files in the VDI to my desktop? Or does anyone know a different way that works?

Comment: If Virtualbox allows to create/mount ,img file as floppy image you can first copy the files to virtual floppy and then mount the same image as virtual floppy drive in windows using third party tools like VDF. If this works you shall however be restricted to 1.4 MB data transfer at a time!!

Comment: Ik, 1.4 is Max for floppy.

Comment: can you give the link for the vdf download

Comment: check http://sourceforge.net/projects/vfd/ however check the compatibility with your version of windows.  Also if Virtualbox or Windows or any other tool allows, you can try mounting the virtual disk on which DOS is installed directly under windows. I am not sure however if that’s supported and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you could mount an image file on DOS as a virtual floppy, then insert that image to a virtual XP and copy it with a flash-drive or another tool.